# How do I make so when user moves the camera it doesn't go beyond the scene borders in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity

How do i make so when i move my camera, it doesn't go beyond the border of the canvas while playing. This is the script i use to make the camera move:

```
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
    {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
        transform.Translate (+touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, +touchDeltaPosition.y * speed, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Watch this tutorial. It is what you are looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhJt0hgwEnc

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Video tutorial by 3D Buzz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u67fbxe8xxY) which does exactly this. In this method, you clamp camera positions and add some offset margin so that the camera gives some leeway to the player before moving to follow player.

Answer (score 0):

an easy solution could be this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
{
    Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;

    vector3 delta = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed,touchDeltaPosition.y * speed , 0);

    if ((transform.position + delta )   is inside your canvas)  /*pseudo code*/
            transform.Translate (+delta.x, +delta.y , 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was built with LibGdx, but you should be able to easily adapt it to your own code:

```
    Camera c = this.getCamera();
    Vector3 camPos = c.position;
    float HW = c.viewportWidth / 2, HH = c.viewportHeight / 2;
    camPos.x = MathUtils.clamp(camPos.x, HW, mapWidth - HW);
    camPos.y = MathUtils.clamp(camPos.y, HH, mapHeight - HH);
```

What this code does is it clamps (keeps the first value between the min and max, the second and thrid value respectively) the x and y positions of the camera to the inside of the map. Because the LibGdx camera's position is at the center of its viewport you need to ensure that the middle is at least half of the width or hight of the viewport from the left and right sides or top and bottom, respectively.

This code should be run after you set the camera's new position since it is post-corrective.